# Ramer-Douglas-Peucker Algorithm with dataset points

Tags: python, algorithm, rdp

In the implementation of rdp algorithm:

```
from rdp import rdp

rdp([[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3], [4, 4]])
```

the points are provided hardcoded.

I have a dataset and I want to read the lon,lat from each point and then to run the algorithm.

Python code:

```
#returns the lon/lat
def load_data_from_file():
    # load the point data
    df = pd.read_csv('/home/repos/master/testdat.csv')
    coordinates = df.as_matrix(columns=['LON', 'LAT'])
    return coordinates

if __name__ == "__main__":
    coordinates_of_file =  load_data_from_file()
    print " \n Initial coordinates pairs:", number_of_initial_points(coordinates_of_file),"\n"

    number_of_pairs = number_of_initial_points(coordinates_of_file)
```

If I perform a loop to gather the lat/lon of the points to execute the algorithm, then the algorithm applies for every pair and not for all pairs.

```
for i in range((number_of_pairs)):
    print "\n rdp (Insight Lab) results: ", rdp([coordinates_of_file[i]],
                                                epsilon=0.05), "\n"
```

I wonder how I can achieve to run the algorithm for all the points from dataset.